# Automatic approach to update remote database with commit using post-receive

Tags: mysql, git, production-environment, git-post-receive

I'm developing a website on my local server and created a remote repository on my host. Updated post-receive to checkout working tree there.

But I can't find a way to update my local database sql to the server database. My current approach is to dump an sql from the local database and on the server side, to manually put them.

I'm looking for any ideas or post-receive customization that will automatically update the remote server database using that sql dump.

**Edit** I'm using mysql on both remote and local server

Comment: You want to create a copy of your local db on the remote host? Or is it about replication? which db are you using?

Comment: Mysql on both remote and local server

Comment: Yes, I want to create a copy of my local db on the remote host. This not about replication. Mysql on both remote and local server